# Hero background-image not displaying when site is uploaded to server?

Tags: html, css

I just uploaded this site: http://suplehoteles.com/

However, the hero background-image won't show. The HTML is there, and the styling too (buttons).
At first there was a carousel and the first image didn't work, so I tried doing a Hero instead.

Any ideas why I doesn't work in the live server? The image does appear in the localhost server.

HTML

```
<div class="hero">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-sm-12">
        <h1 class="carousel-title">Suplimos</h1>
        <p class="textLeft carousel-text">Importadores directos de productos premium de acabados arquitectónicos, diseño y equipamiento. <br><br>Maderas inteligentes, loza, grifería, accesorios, mobiliario, comercial, residencial, luminarias led, muebles de exterior, y decks para hoteles y proyectos.</p>
        <a href="contacto.html" class="smoothScroll button-carousel button btn btn-cotizar">Cotizar</a>
        <a href="#section-2" class="smoothScroll button-carousel button btn btn-producto">Ver productos</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.hero{
    width: 100%;
    padding: 150px 0 150px 0;
    background: url(../assets/img/bathtub-alt.JPG) no-repeat center right;
    @include background-cover;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The background image which is referring in .hero class is not valid. The url which it is referring is "http://suplehoteles.com/assets/img/bathtub-alt.JPG". Check the url of background image.

Comment: I tried doing that and it doesn't work either. I've added a background-color fallback in the meantime. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can try it:

`.hero{
    width: 100%;
    padding: 150px 0 150px 0;
    background: url(http://suplehoteles.com/assets/img/bathtub-alt.JPG) no-repeat center right;
    @include background-cover;
}`